# Randomize blocks of code

Tags: c++

I am pretty new to c++ and i need some help . 
Is there any library or any easy way to randomize blocks of code each time you are compiling the app ?  for example

```
     struct{
          float getNotes()
          { 
            return something;
          }
          float getName()
          {
            return smth;
          }
          float getAge()
          {
            return smths;
          }
    }Students;
```

into

```
     struct{
          float getAge()
          {
            return smths;
          }
          float getName()
          {
            return smth;
          }
          float getNotes()
          { 
            return something;
          }
    }Students;
```

and this to be randomized everytime i am compiling . Thanks for any help !!

Comment: Why would you want to do this ?

Comment: Maybe if you explained what you are trying to accomplish with this, you might get more useful answer answers.

Comment: 1. Why!? It's both equivalent anyway. Or what's its purpose? 2. You can write one yourself, should be straightforward, but it would be a **nightmare** to debug without special debuggers I guess.

Comment: its just an example . i want something which randomizes blocks of code or any idea how i would do that alone ( im a newbie )

Comment: With all due respect are you a newbie to programming in general?  Code is written in logical steps to be executed at certain times, in order and not to be randomly sorted and executed. I am trying to understand why you are trying to achieve this so I can help, but I am lost.

Comment: not in this case (Basically i'm calling voids when i need to , the order doesn't really matter ) . yeah don't worry , i am a newbie .

Comment: If you're trying to do this for code obfuscation purposes (i.e. make it harder to disassemble), then this won't get you what you're trying to achieve; the order of the text itself has little relevance to the actual binary output, especially when it comes to functions within classes/structs. Also, why use C++ to do this? Why not a shell script or a different high-level language?

Comment: i am using it to make a cheat for a game and i really need to do it in c++ . is there any polymorphic library or something ?

Comment: Do you need randomization during compile time or during run-time?

Comment: Do you need random values returned?

Comment: during compile .and no

Answer (score 1):

In that structure you just define some functions that you can use them for many works. But note that there isn't any ordering for functions.

If you want to do some works by random, you can use `switch - case` and create a random number by `rand()` function then switch that number. for example :

```
srand(time(null));
int choice = (rand() % 10) + 1; // create a random number between 1 and 10
switch(choice){
    case 1:
    // do something or calling a function
    break; 

    case 2:
    // do something or calling a function
    break;

    case 3:
    // do something or calling a function
    break;

    ....
    ....
    ....
}
```

for more information read about [rand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/), [srand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/), [switch-case](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson5.html)

good luck